# using pandas to select a column as a condition for another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on my Health data from the iPhone health app. I've made a pandas dataframe using the data, but I want to condense it a but further.
I have the following columns for my steps taken data: unit, startDate, endDate, value. (Please exclude the last column.)
Now, the iPhone records data per minute, a few minutes etc. 
I would like to sum up the counts of the steps per day using the dates of course, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. 
Thank you in advance.
[Pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRlcu.png)

Comment: Please provide [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please paste sample data instead of giving an image

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is create a subset of your dataframe containing only rows where the date is equal to some value. You can do this with the following code:

```
today_df = df[df['startDate']==today]
steps_today = today_df.values.sum()['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to create a time series DataFrame for this kind of problem (which is a DataFrame that has time data as its index):

First, create a 'time_diff' column (optional step):

```
df['time_diff'] = df['end_time'] - df['start_time']
df.drop(columns=['end_time'])
```

Second, make the start time the DataFrame's index:

```
df = df.set_index('start_time')
```

Third, resample the column of `unit` values (or the corresponding column to number of steps) on a daily basis and `.sum()` its contents.

```
df['unit'].resample('D').sum()
```

These steps change a bit of how your data is organized but in general it will make it much easier to manipulate overall.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of problem for which the pandas [grouping and aggregation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) process was designed.

In order to perform a time-based grouping directly on the DataFrame, you must first convert the DataFrame index to a datetime-like object, which can be done via the [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method, using an existing column, as described by @joaoavf.

Alternatively, you can create a [Grouper](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) object for any datetime-like column by providing a key (column name) and frequency (from the available [offset aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)). To wit (where **steps** is the DataFrame):

```
daily = steps.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='startDate', freq='D'))
```

In this case, `daily.sum()` would yield the total step value per day.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however, I can't seem to use this "daily"  after creating it. What I intend to do is make a graph of time vs steps. But when I append daily.sum() to my dataframe, it gives me NaN values. Also, is there a way to use only the date part without time in the datetime feature? I tried another method but it failed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wouldn't want to append the grouped data to the source DataFrame. The aggregation step (`sum`) returns an entirely new DataFrame. [Here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/mgilliam/1e666750ff9fda9d3c090c44a9b4e8e9) is a Jupyter Notebook to illustrate.